# Disabled breakpoints disappear, no more red dot?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

In previous versions of VS, if you right-clicked a breakpoint's red dot and selected Disable Breakpoint, the dot would become 'hollow', and clicking it again would re-enable it. But in VS2008, disabling the breakpoint removes the red dot entirely and you need to go to the Breakpoints window to re-enable.

Anyone know how to get the previous versions' behavior? I have a few BP's that I toggle often, and its a bit of a PITA to do it in this way. I don't understand why MS took this away.

EDIT: I installed SP1 yesterday - because without it, VS would crash as soon as I tried to CTRL+F. Nice testing, Microsoft! Same problem happens pre-SP.

I hadn't touched the default color scheme, and checking it indicates that it should be a hollow dot. I tried changing it to no avail. In fact, I can't even change the enabled breakpoint's color.

This is a Windows XP 64-bit machine. I'm guessing this is the root of the problems.

Comment: I have the same issue on a 32-bit machine, running VS 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in VS 2008 SP1.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=366060

Comment: Good find! It's too bad there are no details there at the moment about when the fix will be available.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me the way you describe but only for specific locations where actual code will get hit, like inside a method body.

Comment: He described two ways: The old way and the "new" (broken) way... Which are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but are you using a Custom Color Scheme?
Is it possible that the colors selected for Disabled Breakpoint effectively 'hide' it?
(EG Black on Black)

Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Fonts/Colors-->BreakPoint (Disabled)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with Visual Studio 2008 SP1. There is a fix available:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912

The associated support page is here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912

And the original bug report is here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=366060

Just follow the first link, then click on downloads. There is a link there to download the hotfix. It now works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The hot fix KB957912 helps to clear this issue but unfortunately the link to the download: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912 is dead.

Answer (score -1):

I have VS2008 SP1 and it has the 'diasble breakpoint' functionality you describe... do you have SP1 installed?  Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: He described two ways: The old way and the "new" (broken) way... Which are you referring to?